# Como trabalhar com split do Javascript com datas?

Tags: javascript

Observem a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O alert que aparece é esse ;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código do javascript é esse;

```
var resultado = $('#idPeriodoInicio').val().split("/");
    alert("o valor do split   " + resultado);
```

**Como faço para ele aparecer assim o 2026?**

O valor original da data é essa!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer que só apareça o 2026?

Comment: Não entendi exatamente o que quer, precisa que apareça apenas o ano ou 4/2026?

Comment: @AndréLins  é isso mesmo, só queria que aparecesse **2026**

Comment: Hmm entendi.. você poderia utilizar algo tipo isso caso já estivesse em formato date:
var dt = new Date();
         document.write("getYear() : " + dt.getFullYear()); 
Porém precisamos primeiro saber como transformar em date passando por parametro para date() a partir do dado do campo pra depois usar o getFullYear()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `split`retorna um array, é só pegar a segunda posição do array como abaixo:

```js
var resultado = $('#idPeriodoInicio').val().split("/");
alert("o valor do split   " + resultado[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="idPeriodoInicio" value="04/2026" />
```